# Include column number in git-grep output

Tags: git, shell

The [silver searcherer](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) has `--column` option that works like this:

```
% ag silver --column               
Brewfile
40:13:install the_silver_searcher
```

where 13 denotes the column where the match (silver) begins.

Is there a way to get something similar with `git-grep`?

**EDIT**

The reason for this is that I want to use `git-grep` as a `grepprg` in vim (much faster in certain cirumstances e.g. node.js project).

Comment: `git grep --column` is here! (soon). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431150/6309)

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), "`git grep`" learned the "`--column`" option that **gives not just the line number but the column number of the hit**.

See [commit 240cf2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/240cf2a25744b45c514fe850363721615a1c4b8c), [commit 6653fec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6653fec3bb969d8be3987cf77654c0aa1778b6b5), [commit a449f27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a449f27ffa08de1b01ab5e4fe7daac38f25c9515), [commit 89252cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89252cd069d4acf1c6c407f00c7a1cc2c6ad3953), [commit 017c0fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/017c0fcfdb21dd44e2c83f533e9a6d78513e7d8c), [commit 68d686e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68d686e6af0fc192fce1788f67bbe0c21a5419ab) (22 Jun 2018), and [commit f8a0c6e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8a0c6e799b98f6b502eadfadcf6acc103d6f7c6) (20 Jun 2018) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d036d66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d036d667b7f297f8305ffaaec212a95da7022ebe), 18 Jul 2018)</sup>

> ### `builtin/grep.c`: add '`--column`' option to '`git-grep(1)`'
>
> Teach '`git-grep(1)`' a new option, '`--column`', to show the column
>   number of the first match on a non-context line.
>   This makes it possible to [teach '`contrib/git-jump/git-jump`' how to seek to the first matching position of a grep match in your editor](https://github.com/git/git/commit/240cf2a25744b45c514fe850363721615a1c4b8c), and allows similar additional
>   scripting capabilities.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $ git grep -n --column foo | head -n3
> .clang-format:51:14:# myFunction(foo, bar, baz);
> .clang-format:64:7:# int foo();
> .clang-format:75:8:# void foo()
> ```

So:

> when running '`git jump grep`', column numbers will also be emitted,
>   e.g. `git jump grep "hello"` would return:
>
> ```
> -----------------------------------
> foo.c:2:9: printf("hello word!\n");
> -----------------------------------
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer I hoped for, but here is a handrolled script that does just that:

```
git grep -n $1 | while read git_grep; do

  file_and_line=$(echo "$git_grep" | cut -d: -f1 -f2)
  match=$(echo "$git_grep" | sed 's/[^:]*:[^:]*:\(.*\)/\1/')
  column=$(echo "$match" | awk "{print index(\$0, \"$1\")}")

  echo "$file_and_line:$column:$match"
done
```

Action:

```
% ./bin/grepprg.sh silver  
Brewfile:40:13:install the_silver_searcher
```